# File system task error :"could not find file..."

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, foreach-loop-container

I have created a simple package in visual studio which use a *ForEach Loop Container* with a `ForEach File Enumerator`.

[image]

I got this error:

> [File System Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Could not find file '\ALDRZFS01\altirrepdev01\WFM_Reports\PROD\QVC\tpDelivery-Src\ALDRZFS01\altirrepdev01\WFM_Reports\PROD\QVC\tpDelivery-Src\TP_EXPORT_220116_1.csv'.".

And these are the variables I have created:

| Variable Name | Variable Value |
| --- | --- |
| varSourceFolder | \ALDRZFS01\altirrepdev01\WFM_Reports\PROD\QVC\tpDelivery-Src |
| varFileName | *.csv |
| varFilePath | @[User::varSourceFolder]+ "\" + @[User::varFileName] |
| varArchiveFolder | @[User::varSourceFolder]+ "\Archive\"+ (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(GETDATE()) + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(GETDATE()) + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(GETDATE()) |
| varArchivePath | @[User::varArchiveFolder]+ "\" + @[User::varFileName] |

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this, please?

Comment: Looks like you are referencing a server name which requires a double backslash. \\ALDRZFS01\altirrepdev01

Comment: AND whenever you have a \ inside quotes it needs to be doubled because \ is an escape character. examples "\t" = tab and "\\" = \

Comment: Thank you!Now the package is executable but the file does not pass to the archive folder and there is a Warning: The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty.
Can you help me with this?

Comment: are you setting the input mask to *.csv? because it looks like you are setting the fileName to that.

Comment: i changed varFileName *.csv  to varFileName  a.csv but still doesnt work

Comment: I just posted two photos of the project...may be clearer

Comment: @IvaXhelili You need to post more details about the `File System Task` and the logic you are trying to implement in this package. Besides, It would be great to check the following topic before writing your first question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you will get more help.